# Why does generating an array in a different way cause massive speed-up of the different part of the code?

Tags: python, performance, sage

I have encountered a very curious case of a massive speed-up in code after changing a seemingly minor detail. I have the following code, which is an implementation of Borwein's algorithm for computing the factorial, implemented in SageMath (but apart from some minor things, like `^` for exponentiation, it should work in pure Python 2.7)

```py
def sieve(n): #My implementation of the sieve of Eratosthenes
    T = [1]*n
    for i in xrange(2,n):
        if T[i]==1:
            for j in xrange(2,ceil(n/i)):
                T[i*j]=0
    return [i for i in xrange(2,n) if T[i]]
def expp(n,p): #Exponent of p in the factorization of n!
    k = p
    s = 0
    while k<=n:
        s += n//k
        k = k*p
    return s
def quick_prod(T): #Computing product of the elements of an array using binary splitting
    if len(T)==1:
        return T[0]
    if len(T)==2:
        return T[0]*T[1]
    if len(T)>2:
        s = len(T)//2
        return quick_prod(T[0:s])*quick_prod(T[s:len(T)])

n = 10^6
P = sieve(n) #Array of primes up to n
exps = [expp(n,p) for p in P] #exponents of all primes in P
l = len(bin(abs(n)))-2
nums = [quick_prod([P[j] for j in xrange(len(P)) if (exps[j] >> i)%2])^(2^i) for i in range(l)] #Array of numbers appearing in Borwein's algorithm, whose product is n!
quick_prod(nums)
```

(Excuse my awful naming conventions (and probably other poor coding practices), I am an amateur and only really code things "quick and dirty")

I did not expect this code to be particularly efficient, so I was not surprised to see it took 10 minutes to run. But when I've started tinkering with the code to try and improve it, I've noticed that replacing the line `P = sieve(n)` with `P = prime_range(n)` (which produces the same array, except it uses a function which is built-in in SageMath) decreased the run time to 3.5 seconds.

Now, when I saw this, my first thought was that the explanation is obvious - my implementation of the sieve must be so horrible it took ages, and `prime_range` does this so much more efficiently. But the results have surprised me - `sieve(10^6)` took 4 seconds, while `prime_range(10^6)` took 2 seconds. This is not even close to explaining the difference of 10 minutes!

Some of the ideas me and my friends had which could possibly explain it:

- The two arrays may be different, e.g. they may be ordered differently. This is not the case, as `sieve(10^6)==prime_range(10^6)` returns `True`
- Despite the equality, the arrays may be stored as different types. `type(...)` returns `list` for both.
- Intermediate results getting cached. Probably not the case, since the results are approximately the same regardless of compilation order, even after restarting the kernel.

The only way such a massive speed-up (or slow-down, depending how you look at it) could come to be is if the original code somehow returned to the way P was generated *after* computing it. What could possibly explain this behavior?

Comment: My guess is that sieve is spawning a lots of lists, you would want to try generators instead. Just replace `[list comprehension expression]` by `(list comprehension expression)` and it would stop to spawning a lot of lists in the ram

Comment: Specifically `T = [1]*n` for `n = 10^6` will spawn `10^6` references, or more!?

Comment: In fact `10^6` is 12, not 1000000 I just get couch by this

Comment: @geckos RE your last point: in SageMath, `^` by default denotes exponentiation, not bitwise XOR (as I mention in the first paragraph). I will try your suggestion from the first comment when I get a chance.

Comment: In python is `**`, am I wrong?

Comment: @geckos You are right.

Comment: The [`prime_range` docs](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/fast_arith.html#sage.rings.fast_arith.prime_range) say that it returns a list of Sage Integers rather than Python ints. What performance do you see if you pass `py_ints=True` to `prime_range`, which causes it to return a list of Python ints?

Answer (score 0):

SageMath (which I am not familiar with) probably works like numpy.  That is to say that the array structure and internal data types it uses (and returns) is a lot more efficient than standard python lists.  This may apply to list comprehensions and other calculations you perform with it afterward.

Here's an example of this phenomenon (based on numpy).

```
import numpy as np
def sieve2(n):
    s       = np.ones(n+1)
    s[4::2] = 0
    s[:2]   = 0
    p = 3
    while p*p<=n:
        if s[p]:s[p*p::p] = 0
        p+=2
    return np.arange(n+1)[s==1]
```

This function returns the primes up to 10^6 in 0.013 second, compared to your function which takes 0.27 on my computer (roughly 20 times faster).  The numpy based function returns a numpy array which has its own implementation of basic functions such as additions, multiplications, exponentiations, etc.  This may also be the case for sageMath which would possibly accelerate other parts of your program.

*Note that the great time difference using numpy comes from its ability to vectorize calculations and use the GPU to perform multiple operations in parallel. SageMath could be using the same trick for its big integer calculations (which Python probably doesn't do)*

Comment: `type` reported it's just a list, though. I'm guessing it's actually due to a difference in the integer type used.

Comment: You should check type(P[0]) to see if the numeric type is different.  Pyhton's integers are not necessarily the best performers for huge numeric values that go beyond 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

As [you can see in the source code](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/master/src/sage/rings/fast_arith.pyx), `prime_range` is a [Cython](https://cython.org) function, which means that pure C code is generated from this, using C integers.

```
cpdef prime_range(start, stop=None, algorithm="pari_primes", bint py_ints=False):
```

In addition, it is using the ultra-fast [Pari](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr) library for a lot of the dirty work.  So yes, it should be much, much faster.

When we try to [time](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtTz0LwjAQ3Qv9DwcOTYpg6-AgZHR06xYiFL3oleYiaRT997aGgopve1_3uBNaGAjvKFhuYbF_Arlrjw45tpE8g7cQL5gyE9mFNvphlBiHPIMRDSjQtSk5UesDEBDDI7R8RrFejpeTNYEsNJqMUvWHOPe6r94RqRe8Iil_ou9VTWVnVJWcgPEWGDT9nZ9HTZ7lWSSHFEWRvq6rw0YW8gXSGkiB&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) your code, it actually takes between 1 and 2 seconds; `timeit('prime_range(10^6)')` gives more like 12 milliseconds.  Still not so bad, and clearly not responsible for all of your slow timing.

So user2357112 and Alain T. are correct; your type is somehow still Python `int`s.  This is subtle - `xrange` and `range` return `int`s, while `srange` (for "Sage range") will return `<type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>`, which has lots of custom methods available.  [Trying your code with this change in a way that we can time it easily](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUsGO2jAQvSPxD7NCq8aUCshhD6hBaqs9VuLALTIrAwMMJLZrO13o19eOkwDL-mSPZ-bNm_e2uANL-BcTyWYw-H0BKnWBJUonHCkJagfugDEnPF6NcMr6kETb74E_S8ggn_KhjM-dMkBAEs5GyD0m6ch3jl_h0A6WOfEsm94E27pjqLNt3QapSOSYGPuQWqPmNDzybBJ_DLrKSMjpCm-v8C0o7_e2ni-etU7kSAfCr2etpCcbqOlQFsjuxMYpQ_-6DcinCHPyVHW8Wn9twN8PVCCcvmfyZk4LXzOQ4_HpGgrVp6G-m9jGkf5UtDm9aaO2yTKM9UuVunIk9xBi1ca1OmDUxoa3kCCMEReobMhckxTmAlYX5EJpxPHUC5S-6_3GG_hlPuEPeennecOlV_lD8jy9o5w14fE4fWhxSzGfzCxnw7uQncVazvq9uJQ9ujdySWefhe_fehUGP2rqQTZDJVqoNDgFjQm9xGGavJO69kUt8ILDABvV4xqLou0RvmODouHil5qItfWIjH1rSMmqrJvfjJ8v8iO_WrixfmiwYLX9kjBRyJnPgdhzytkqSVfErn5tShi_oeaR1mgsCK1RmCCyT_ypzDuS_OLDxd7b1B3KkfegstiZhWxn2cfth_HrHT87T7rd8nSyemH_AVK1LNM=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) gives a much more manageable outcome of under 10 seconds.

This is annoying, but I promise it's a feature, not a bug!  But knowing when Sage `Integer`s versus Python `int`s are being used is a good practice to keep aware of when using Sage.  It is based on Python, but it's not quite the same thing.

---

Finally, in the future I'd recommend using Sage builtins whenever possible.  They aren't all optimized, but usually they are a lot better than whatever can be done naively.  Not that trying to code it isn't a useful exercise!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, how are you getting those 10 minutes?

On my machine I can't get more than a few seconds.
More precisely I defined the following test function:

```
def test(fun_to_test, type_to_test, n):
     P = [type_to_test(i) for i in fun_to_test(n)]
     exps = [expp(n,p) for p in P]
     l = len(bin(abs(n)))-2
     nums = [quick_prod([P[j] for j in xrange(len(P)) if (exps[j] >> i)%2])^(2^i) for i in range(l)]
     return quick_prod(nums)
```

and I get those timings:

```
sage: %time r0 = test(sieve, int, n)
CPU times: user 5.47 s, sys: 62.7 ms, total: 5.53 s
Wall time: 5.53 s
sage: %time r1 = test(prime_range, int, n)
CPU times: user 4.39 s, sys: 34.3 ms, total: 4.43 s
Wall time: 4.43 s
sage: %time r2 = test(sieve, Integer, n)
CPU times: user 1.95 s, sys: 50.4 ms, total: 2 s
Wall time: 1.99 s
sage: %time r3 = test(prime_range, Integer, n)
CPU times: user 917 ms, sys: 28.6 ms, total: 945 ms
Wall time: 936 ms
```

You can see what takes time in your code like this:

```
sage: %prun r0 = test(sieve, Integer, n)
         893200 function calls (760228 primitive calls) in 2.057 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.949    0.949    0.987    0.987 <ipython-input-38-92e1b030cb97>:1(sieve)
132993/21    0.509    0.000    0.528    0.025 <ipython-input-38-92e1b030cb97>:15(quick_prod)
        1    0.490    0.490    2.041    2.041 <ipython-input-51-ed2c358da30e>:1(test)
    78498    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 <ipython-input-38-92e1b030cb97>:8(expp)
    78498    0.024    0.000    0.039    0.000 other.py:213(__call__)
   446208    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 {len}
        1    0.016    0.016    2.057    2.057 <string>:1(<module>)
    78498    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 {method 'ceil' of 'sage.rings.rational.Rational' objects}
    78498    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {bin}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {abs}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```